# Theorems in number theory whose first proofs were long and difficult

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, math-history, big-list

What are the examples of important theorems of number theory that has been shown to have surprisingly simple proofs though their first demonstration wasn't at all simple enough. Now *simple proof* is an ambiguous term but in this case it may be defined as a proof which is both short and [elementary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_proof). As an example, the Kelly's proof of [Sylvester-Gallai Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) may be consdered.

Comment: What's "upto college level"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Standard college level mathematics.

Comment: I *really* don't know what that means. Does college mathematics refer to what a math undergrad level would learn, in which year? Does it include grad level courses? Are we talking about a college where the set theory department is very strong, or are we talking about a college that employs no set theorists whatsoever?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: See the edit and tell me if it's okay.

Comment: Well, elementary is still not a well-defined notion. It's slightly better than "college level", though.

Comment: I hope that you don't mind, but since you've added "number theory" to the body, I figured that it should also be in the tags and title.

Comment: I will be very interested to see what the __most important__ theorem with the __most surprisingly simple__ proof ends up being in this list!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to think that [my proof (with Jonathan Sondow) of this classical divisibility theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0076.pdf?origin=publication_detail) — previous proofs of which used the theory of primitive roots, or Bernoulli numbers, or Lagrange’s theorem on roots of polynomials — might count as a surprisingly simple and elegant proof of a [relatively] important theorem.

Answer (score 4):

This example may be stretching the number theory context of your question, but it does at least involve the set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers, and a significant part of elementary number theory is equivalent to finite set theory. (*see comments for this answer.)

It is a well known result that $\mathbb Q$ is countable - i.e., there is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$.

However, for over one-hundred years, no one was able to explicitly state such a bijection.  Rather, the proof relied on arranging $\mathbb Q$ in an infinite array including may redundant entries - e.g. $\frac11, \frac22, \frac33, \dots$

This method of proof is not difficult, but it is unnecessarily long and involves *skipping over* redundant entries.

Then, in $1989$, Yoram Sagher noticed a rather simple explicit bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q^{+}$.

Let $\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb Q^{+}$ with $gcd(n,m)=1$, and let $q_1, q_2, \dots, q_k$ be the prime factors of $n$.  Then
$$f(\frac{m}{n}) = m^2n^2/(q_1q_2\cdots q_k)$$
is the desired bijection.  Given the simplicity of $f$, it is surprising that no one had noticed it before.

Note that the inverse is (easily) computable, so you say what the $n$'th rational number listed is for any $n$.

You can read details here : [Counting the rationals quickly](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2004/03/counting-rationals-quickly.html)

Comment: Number theory is not equivalent to finite set theory. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @KCd It was proven by Ackermann in 1937 - or at least that is what I have read recently.

Comment: @KCd I've just read the quote in my text (Stillwell; The Real Numbers).  He apparently proved that they are "essentially" equivalent.

Comment: That is using a strange definition of "number theory". Just because a result involves the positive integers does not make it number theory, and not everything in number theory is about the positive integers (or prime numbers).

Comment: @KCd Number theory in 1937 was probably just higher arithmetic on the integers.  I can't say for sure what Stillwell meant.  I'm still at an introductory level.

Comment: Number theory was most definitely *not* just about the integers in 1937. For instance, the basic facts of class field theory were already known by then. I looked in Stillwell's book on the history of math where he discusses the result of Ackermann, and it relies on declaring that  combinatorics is just a name for the theory of finite sets and elementary number theory is just a name for the theory of the positive integers. Neither description is a fair reflection of what the subjects are really about.

Comment: @KCd I take your point.  Even for someone at my level it is clear that Number Theory is bigger than arithmetic on $ \mathbb N $.  And yes, Stillwell does frame his comment in the context of Elementary number theory.  Should I modify my answer to say : parts of elementary n.t. are equiv. to finite s.t.?

Comment: The result you are describing is about the positive rational numbers and involves prime factorization, but whether or not number theory is equivalent in some sense to studying finite sets is irrelevant to it.

Comment: @KCd Here is Stillwell's exact quote: "In fact, Ackermann (1937) showed that number theory is essentially identical to finite set theory.  We will return to this surprising result in Sect. 6.6. when we will develop a clearer picture of what set theory actually is."  I haven't gotten as far as Sect. 6.6.  The quote is from page 131 of the first edition of The Real Numbers.  AHHH! Apparently it is based on Grassmann's concept of n.t.

Comment: @KCd By "elementary number theory", in this context, what is meant is the first-order formalization of Peano arithmetic. This is indeed mutually interpretable with finite set theory (the theory resulting from starting with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and replacing the axiom of infinity with its negation). "Mutual interpretability" is a technical concept, it implies that the two theories are equivalent (there are recursive translation procedures that turn statements, and proofs, in one theory into statements, and proofs, in the other).

Comment: @KCd This meaning of "elementary number theory" is of course not the standard usage of the term, but it actually covers a fair ground, as there are ("well known") reduction procedures that turn most of the techniques from analysis, algebraic number theory, and algebraic geometry that come up in current practice into appropriate statements provable in Peano arithmetic. (That said, I do not know of any references where the scope of these reductions is formalized or discussed in detail.)

Answer (score 3):

Quadratic reciprocity is an example.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure it can really be classified as “important”, but… the first case (*i.e.* where $\gcd(xyz,n)=1$) of Fermat’s Last Theorem for even exponents. In 1977, Terjanian gave a proof which “require[d] only elementary considerations, so it is surprising that it was not found beforehand” [Ribenboim].